# jQuery and PHP clashing

Tags: php, jquery, blogs, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page that has a slide show, jQuery accordion and blog section. Everything works fine on localhost and I therefore uploaded it to my server. Now everything falls apart! Once on the server the accordion and slide show do not work. After playing around with the code looking for the problem I have realized that:

If I remove just the blog php code (pasted below) from the page the accordion and slideshow work fine but obviously no blog.

If I remove just the jquery accordion code (pasted below) the slideshow and blog both work but obviously no accordion.

I have no idea why everything is working fine on localhost but not on the actual server? I also have no idea where to begin to look?

here is the link to the offending file:
http://www.darrenmorton.co.uk/blog/comments/index.php

Thank you for any help.

Below is the code (both are within the same sheet).

```
<!--jQuery accordion-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $("#accordion").accordion({active: false, collapsible: true, icons: {'header': 'ui-icon-plus', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-minus'}});
  });
 </script>



    <!--Blog section-->

    <div class="container" id="six"><!--Comment section-->              
        <?php /*
        //Simple login
        echo '<div style="float:right;">';
        if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
            echo 'Logged as <a href="account.php">'.$_SESSION['user']['name'].'</a> | <a href="account.php?page=logout">Logout</a>';
        else echo '<a href="account.php?page=login" class="btn">Login</a> <a href="account.php?page=signup" class="btn">Sign up</a>';
        echo'</div>'; */
        ?>              
        <!--<a href="admin">Admin Dashboard Here !</a> | <a href="index2.php">Template #2</a> <br></br>-->
        <?php               
        //Include Comments Class
        require_once('includes/Comments.class.php');
        $Comments = new Comments();             
        //Set some custom config. NOTE: Not all config options will work here ! Read the documentation.
        $config = array(
            'page_title' => 'My Page', //This is your page title, it's optional
        );
        $Comments->set_config($config);             
        //Display comments
        $Comments->display_comments();
        ?>
    </div><!--End comment section-->
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you have a duplicate ID somewhere. Also that you didn't bother checking the error console.

Comment: Yeah please check the console and tell us what it says if you are still stuck

Comment: I am self taught and there are lots of areas I am not sure about. It did cross my mind that this could be down to a clash of id's but I do not know how I would find if that was the problem. Is the error console within firebug right? I will take a look in there but am not sure exactly what part of firebug. I will take a look now.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I have checked the error console in Firebug now and it returns nothing. There are plenty of Warnings though. If this is a clash of ID's is there anything else I can do in Firebug to help me find / fix this? It's good for me because I am at least learning here : ) I will use Firebug more often now. I should be using it anyway I guess.